# How to find eigenvalues of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If the eigenvalues of $A_{m\times m}$ are $\lambda_1 \le 
>  \lambda_2 \le \lambda_3 \le \dotsb \le \lambda_m$ then find the eigenvalues of $B$ where
>   $$B=\begin{bmatrix} C &D\\E&A\end{bmatrix}$$ where
>   $$C=I_{k\times k}$$ and $$D=J_{k\times m},E=J^t$$ where $J$ is the all $1$ matrix.
>
> Here $C,D,E,A $ are so arranged such that $B$ is a symmetric $(m+k) \times (m+k)$ matrix.

Is there any way I can find the eigenvalues of the above matrix?

Any help will be highly helpful.

Comment: Please give the dimensions of your matrices. $E=J^t$ suggests $A$ and $C$ don't have the same size. And give some context : is it an exercise ? a question you thought about ?

Comment: In general you cannot deduce the eigenvalues of $B$ from those of $A$. However, if $C$ is $k\times k$, we do know that $k-1$ eigenvalues of $B$ are equal to $1$ and by Cauchy's interlacing inequality, the eigenvalues of $A$ are interlaced between the remaining $n+1$ eigenvalues of $B$.

Comment: If $\mathbf{1}_n$ (the vector of all ones) is an eigenvector of $A$, then all the eigenvalues of $B$ can be easily obtained in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e how to obtain it,can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $B$, and partition it as such:
$$v=\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}$$
where I assume that $C$ is $n$ x $n$ and $x$ has $n$ rows; where as $A$ is $m$ x $m$ and $y$ has $m$ rows.

Then, $B v = \gamma v$, where $\gamma$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ to be determined.  As mentioned earlier, there is a multiplicity of eigenvalues at $\gamma = 1$. To determine the rest, we assume that $\gamma \neq 1$. Doing some algebra gives:

$Cx + Jy = \gamma x$ and $J^tx + Ay = \gamma y$. Thus, $x = \frac{1}{\gamma-1}Jy$. (For completion, you can obtain the eigenvectors for $\gamma =1$ cases by finding the null space of $J^t$.) Substituting, we get:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma-1}J^tJy + Ay -\gamma y = 0$$

Look at the eigenvector decomposition of $A = V\Lambda V^{-1}$, where $V=[v_1, v_2, ... v_n]$ and $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_n)$. Then, $$\frac{1}{\gamma-1}J^tJy + V\Lambda V^{-1}y -\gamma y = 0$$ Let $u=V^{-1}y$ and substituting:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma-1}J^tJVu + V\Lambda u -\gamma Vu = 0$$ Multiplying on the left by $V^{-1}$, then
$$\frac{1}{\gamma-1}V^{-1}J^tJVu + (\Lambda -\gamma I) u = 0$$

Notice that $J = \mathbf 1_n$ x $\mathbf 1_m^t$, and thus the above equation can be rewritten as $\frac{n}{\gamma-1}ab^tu + (\Lambda -\gamma I) u = 0$ where $a=V^{-1} \mathbf 1_m$ and $b^t=\mathbf 1_m^t V$ are column vectors. This implies
$$\text{det} \left(\frac{n}{\gamma-1}ab^t + (\Lambda -\gamma I) \right)= 0$$ which can then be solved for $\gamma$.